# Apache NiFi NTLM Authentication 401

Tags: apache-nifi, ntlm-authentication

I'm having troubles authenticating NiFi to a SOAP WebService, using a NTLM Authentication.

I've using this custom processor:
https://github.com/peetkes/nifi-http-processor

I've created a simple flow, with a FlowFile that contains the XML request, passed to the CustomInvokeHTTP Processor.

The problem is that I obtain "Error 401 Unauthorized".

I tried to use the same credentials with SOAPUI and they work.

I attach the flow and the processor properties.

[image: flow]

[image: properties1]

[image: properties2]

[image: properties3]

Is there something else I can try?
I don't really know what to do.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a custom processor that hasn't been updated in 2 years, I wouldn't have much hope in it working...but it looks like you arent setting the NTLM domain.

Comment: Yeah @Sdairs I supposed that too...Yes I didn't set the domain because on SOAPUI I didn't set it.
I also tried another thing, but doesn't work. 
I created a PHP script using cURL and echo the header request.
So I copied the Auth header and on NiFi I added a new property "Authorization NTLM ......" but I get error 400.